# What Halo: Reach Energy Sword Changes Were Made?

Tags: halo-reach

In the January update by 343 Industries for Halo: Reach, I've noticed the Energy Sword has changed quite a bit. It seems to work better in the TU (Title Update) playlists, but for the most part, I seem to be having problems lunging while the reticle is red. What has changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Title Update removes sword blocking (as well as a few other things), but other than that, no major changes have been listed in the [change log](http://halo.xbox.com/Forums/yaf_postst39860_Halo--Reach-Matchmaking-Update-Changelists.aspx). If they made any other changes they were behind the scenes.